# Copulas and the Split VP Hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, copula, auxiliary-verbs, verb-phrase

Copulas are regarded as semantically vacuous auxiliaries merged in V, then raised to T. Lexical verbs are merged in V and are raised to v. I have not found any literature discussing the copula with regards to the split VP hypothesis.

Therefore, this question remains: Is the copula merged in V or v?

If you have found any references or links to articles discussing this, please post the link or title in the comments section.

My bet is that it is merged in v like light verbs.

Comment: Yes, copulae are similar to light verbs in some aspects so “v” makes sense. Then again, they mostly govern nominals so there status is somewhat fuzzy.

Comment: @Atamiri The problem is that the copula is in V in a causative sentence like “I let him be himself”. If it is true that the copula originates in v, then there should be competition between the copula and the causative verb.

Comment: I see your point. The same can happen with auxiliaries too. But there are languages where causatives can be iterative so the phrasal mechanisms has to allow for “competing” nodes anyway.